# Slick database configurations changed to URL and now requests are slow

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I am using Slick to access a database on my local machine. The configurations I previously used are

```
db = {
  connectionPool = "HikariCP" 
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    serverName = "localhost"
    portNumber = "5432"
    databaseName = "postgres"
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

This worked great.

Now I am deploying to Heroku. Since Heroku gives database access in the form of an environment variable, I changed my configs to consume a URL. Note all this is still running on my local machine:

```
db = {
  dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource" 
  driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
  properties = {
    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver$"
    url = "jdbc:"${DATABASE_URL}
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

For whatever reason, performance has slowed to a crawl. I have managed to get a few requests through but the majority have timed out.

I confirmed my url parses correctly to `jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/postgres`, and that my `db.forConfig("db") method returns`. I don't understand why everything else takes so long, I have timeouts/error handling on the Future returned from queries so I should see that, but I just have my client connection timing out.

The other thing is that it's now impossible to exit the program without ctrl+C; I have it setup so that it gracefully terminates when I hit enter, but now it goes through the termination routine (including `db.close()`) and then stays hung until I force it to die. What's going on?

Comment: Have you noticed that you not only changed the way of defining an URL but also datasource implementation and a thread pool? Previously you used Hikari which is one of faster CP for JDBC and replaced it with some Slick defaults. Which do not make closing connection easy as you noticed.

Comment: Does Hikari only use jdbc? What's a good connection pool for non-jdbc connections?

Comment: For non-JDBC connections I think you cannot use Slick. It targets only SQL and SQL-like languages (syntax wise) which have almost exclusively JDBC drivers. There are some alternatives AFAIK but they are either dead (postgresql-async) or they don't target Slick (e.g. tpolecat's skunk) - with JDBC being standard on JVM hardly anyone tries to reinvent it. Hikari is JDBC-only, it basically provides connection pool to JDBC driver. But you have no reason to avoid JDBC if you are using Postgres.

Comment: You can just initiate pass config to Driver manually in your code, like here: https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.1.0-M2/database.html#using-a-database-url